# Where can I change the Shopping cart title?

Tags: cart, template, magento-1, localisation

On the checkout/cart page I need to change the Shopping cart title.

Where can I find it in the code?

Comment: Am new to magento platform.Please help me on this

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

> **Never edit core files in Magento!**

### Solution without changing core files

You can define custom translations in your theme, create the following file if it does not exist yet:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

(replace `en_US` if you use a different language)

Note that this should be a project specific theme, not `rwd/default` or `some_bought_theme/default`. If you did not already, you can add a child theme next to `default` and specify this one as theme in the system configuration. You don't need to copy anything from the `default` directory since Magento falls back automatically, so you only need to add the files that are customized.

In the `translate.csv` you can add your custom translations. Since the translated string is "Shopping Cart" and it's coming from the `Mage_Checkout` module, you need to add this line:

```
"Mage_Checkout::Shopping Cart","Whatever you want to display instead"
```

Answer (score 0):

The file in question is:

`/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`

- Check line 180 (in version 1.9.1)

`->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Shopping Cart'));`

Although you should not be editing any core files so you remain update-friendly.

---

*EDIT:*

To change the page heading you need to go to your theme and open (based on the 1.9.1 RWD theme):

`/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`

and look for and edit:

`<h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart') ?></h1>`

Although, again, as explained in my comments you could simply edit your locale file and 'translate' what you wish to change.

eg:

`/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv` and see in line 295:

`"Shopping Cart","Shopping Cart"`

and change this to:

`"Shopping Cart","Whatever text you want to show instead!!"`

Comment: Thanks I can able to edit the title.Inside checkout/cart/ page also I need to change . can you please say the file name with file path

Comment: Change what else (you didn't supply any info!)? Generally speaking you should use a custom language file in your themes locale to 'translate' the text you wish to change.

Comment: Tecjam can you please help me

Comment: Inside checkout/cart page there is Shopping cart heading and proceed with check out button.Could you please tell me where to change the shopping cart heading .I mean which file and file path.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: In this checkout/onepage/ Can you please say me where the heading checkout comes.I want the file name and file path

Comment: Hi ..I have added some text in checkout/onepage/ .I need to translate that text in french.Could you please in which csv file i need to change and file path too

Comment: Anyone could you please help me out in this.

Comment: I've already given you the answer above! Define your text using the __() function: `<?php echo $this->__('Here is your text!!!') ?>` and then define a new line in either your themes locale .csv or Mage_Checkout.csv and add `"Here is your text!!!","Here is your translated text!!!"`

Answer (score 0):

As I already answered at ["Change Shopping Cart Title"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111791/change-shopping-cart-title) article...

**The best and easiest solution that I found** and that will not affect the default **MAGENTO 2** structure (just changed under my theme) is by [Prashant Valanda](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/28492/prashant-valanda) on ["How to modify page title?"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115281/82325) article.

Basically you just need to add this code in your `XML` file. In this case `checkout_cart_index.xml`:

```xml
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Basket</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

After change doesn't forget to flush the cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```