# Change Shopping Cart Title

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

I am trying to change "Shopping Cart" to "Basket" on both the `h1.page-title` and in the `<title>` tag itself.

Where can I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change this directly in the checkout i18l file:

```
app/code/Magento/Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv
```

in your theme, like:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv

Just change string translation like this:

```
"Shopping Cart","Basket"
```

Result:

[image: result]

Or you can create a language pack https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html

To translate a minicart title you must run `setup:static-content:deploy` with required parameters ([More Info in DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)). After that translations must present in the `js-translation.json` file (`pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US/js-translation.json`):

[image: js-translation file example]

and result will be visible on the frontend:

[image: result on the frontend]

Answer (score 3):

The best and easiest solution that I found and that will not affect the default **MAGENTO 2** structure (just changed under my theme) is by [Prashant Valanda](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/28492/prashant-valanda) on ["How to modify page title?"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115281/82325) article.

Basically you just need to add this code in your `XML` file. In this case `checkout_cart_index.xml`:

```xml
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Basket</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

After change doesn't forget to flush the cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

I found in my case where I needed to change the `<title/>` tag, an "after" plugin can be used on the cart `Index->execute();` controller method.

The page title is set in

```
\** \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index **\
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Shopping Cart'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

Here is my plugin `afterExecute()`

```
/**
 * Custom cart index page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
 */
public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index $cartIndex,
    $resultPage
)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('TITLE TAG CONTENT HERE'));

    $titleBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
    if ($titleBlock) {
        $titleBlock->setPageTitle(
            __('PAGE CONTENT TITLE HERE')
        );
    }
    return $resultPage;
}
```