# How Change Shopping Cart Page Title programmatically

Tags: cart, magento-2.0

I follow this  link [Change Shopping Cart Title](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111791/change-shopping-cart-title)   to change  Shopping cart to some text via language package.

I need to change Programmaticly **Shopping cart** Page title to **MyCart**

I try this

app/design/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head><title> My Cart</title></head>

    </page>
```

Its not Working for me, Suggest me How to Do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override here `/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php`

find the below line

```
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Shopping Cart'));
```

and change to

```
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Whatever Title You Need'));
```

for alternate solution you can create own module that contains a translation file i18n/en_US.csv. here you can translate your phrase

```
'Shopping Cart','Whatever Title You Need'
```

for one more alternate solution you can try with in your theme too

`magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv`

```
'Shopping Cart','Whatever Title You Need'
```