# Magento 2: add admin page content title in layout xml?

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, admin-controller

I noticed that you can set the page title in the layout xml per [how to modify page title](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115273/how-to-modify-page-title).

but it's not working in the admin - if I want to change the admin page title, in the Controller, this works:

```
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Customers Now Online'));
```

Is there a way to set the result content page title in the layout xml?

Comment: Did you try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115273/how-to-modify-page-title?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

Add this in Block file  which is associated to phtml file.

```
 public function getHeader()
        {
            if ($this->getProduct()->getId()) {
                $header = $this->escapeHtml($this->getProduct()->getName());
            } else {
                $header = __('New Product');
            }
            return $header;
        }
```

Change this function as your requirement.
Also header need to declare into xml file.